# How to bindkey Shift+Backspace to backward-delete-word?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, zsh

I want to bind key <kbd>⇧</kbd> <kbd>⌫</kbd> to `backward-delete-word` in my zsh, so what is the corresponding `bindkey` command, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it accidentally, try:

1. <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> > Profiles > Keyboard > <kbd>[+]</kbd> > define output of <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌫</kbd>, say `helloworld`.
   (should be something like `^[[2;1~` though)
2. In your `.zshrc` file, add the followings lines

```
# Comment for your key bindings
bindkey "helloworld" backward-delete-word
```

Now it should work.